# Torque and Equilibrium

Tags: trigonometry, physics, mathematical-physics

> [image]
>
> The spheres $K$ and $L$ are in equilbrium as seen at the diagram. The each sphere has the weight of $40N$. If there's no friction force, find the applying force to each other. $\sin(37) = 0,6$ ; $\cos(37) =0.8$

When I intended to try the formula/strategy on my textbook, I couldn't find anything useful. Will we use Lami's theorem? I'm currently out of my knowledge.

Comment: The strategy is to do free body diagrams and try to balance the forces.

Comment: @ja72 How? Isn't it related to equilibrium? I could see if it is on my textbook. Otherwise, you can tell me what topic this is related to, then I might search it on my textbook. Am I missing something while searching it?

Comment: Can anyone take a look? I really don't know what to do right now.

Comment: Where is the diagram showing static equilibrium?

Comment: Can someone take a look?

Comment: @Liam there are two normal force on K, and one downward force of weight. Also, normal forces are normal to surface of contact of application

Comment: I found the answer as $19.2N$, is it correct?

Comment: @Liam What about the given solution? any doubt on it?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

- draw a free body diagram with acting forces
- write down equilibrium equations

Notably we obtain

[image]

- Equilibrium in horizontal direction: $\sum F_x=0 \implies V\cos 53°-H=0$
- Equilibrium in vertical direction: $\sum F_y=0 \implies V\sin 53°-Mg=0$

then

- $N=\frac{Mg}{\sin 53°} \implies H= V\cos 53° = Mg \cot53°\approx40N\cdot 0.753\approx 30.14 N$

Comment: The thing I'm trying to get is how to find that on my physics textbook. How should I search it?

Comment: now I can’t give more than an hint, later I can try to give some more information

Comment: It's not important to give hint. I'm wondering what topic this question is related to. When I tried to search it on ''Static Equilibrium'', there wasn't anything useful, just Lami's theorem and others.

Comment: I'd be grateful If you tell me what to search.

Comment: static equilibrium is the correct topic

Comment: However, I'm just seeing Lami's theorem. It says something like $\sum F_x = 0$, $\sum F_y = 0$, $\sum F_z = 0$ Is this what I'm trying to find?

Comment: It is the static equilibrium for translation in 3 dimensions. Here you can refer to 2 dimensional form.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Or $\vec {F} =  T_1 + \cos (53) + T_2 \cos (53) - F = 0$ Is this correct?

Comment: Let use symmetry!

Comment: and you need only vertical equilibrium

Comment: I really don't get what you mean.

Comment: And there's nothing about Vertiacl Equilibrium on my textbook.

Comment: Or did you mean ''Dynamics in Two Dimensions''?

Comment: I mean static, find the force direction by geometry and write the equation of equilibrium in vertical direction $\sum F_z =0$.

Comment: What equation do you mean? I'm trying to find that on my textbook, how should I search it as? because there should be a formula.

Comment: Later I will prepare a sketch for you. I’m sorry but I cannot now.

Comment: Yeah but it's enough to tell how to search it as, I'm wondering if there's a solution on my textbook. In my perspective, there's something like Lami's theorem and wire bands. You probs got what I mean.

Comment: Meanwhile take a look here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram and here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statics

Comment: I still didn't get it lol.

Comment: I already know how to draw free body diagram, the thing I'm trying to get is how to find it on statics. You had told something like vertical...

Comment: Found the answer as $19.2N$, is it correct?

Comment: Let me verify, I’ll update with full solution and explanation within a few!

Comment: @Liam I 've found 30.14 N, sorry for the notation I've colled the normal force N to not be confused with N newton, I revise this part

Answer (score 0):

If
$$mg \sin \phi \cos \phi $$
Then
$$40 \times \sin (37) \times cos(37)$$
Hence we get

$$40 \times 0.8 \times 0.6 = \boxed {19.2N}$$

Hope it helps!

Comment: How did you obtain 19.2?